# c++ - How to get first and second element of pair if used as key in map?

Tags: c++, maps, std-pair

I was trying to get first and second element of pair when i am using pair as key in map.For better clarification please see code below.This is what i have tried

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
// your code goes here
map<pair<int,int>,int>mp;
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)cin>>a[i];
int y=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    mp.insert(make_pair(y,a[i]));
    y=a[i]+1;
}
int m;
cin>>m;
int q[m];
for(int i=0;i<m;++i)cin>>q[i];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    int temp=q[i];
    for(map<pair<int,int>,int>::iterator it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();++it)
    {
        if(((it->first)<=temp)&&((it->second)>=temp))
        cout<<mp->second<<endl;
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

I want to get first and second element of key here.How can i do that ?

Comment: As usual? The key is always `it->first`, so use e.g. `it->first.first`.

Comment: @JBL Unfortunately Not

Comment: And what's the output of your compiler? You should have a pretty much self-explanatory error on the `if` line inside your loop.

Comment: it->first->first and it->first->second ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sir,Are it->first->first and it->first.first same ?

Comment: @JBL Sir its not giving any familiar error to me.The error are like /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = int; _U2 = int; _T1 = const std::pair<int, int>; _T2 = int]':
prog.cpp:14:30:   required from here

Comment: @chotabheem Not at all, '.' is a direct accessor but '->' means access to a pointer data or iterator data (or something more special in specific cases, both are overloadable operators)

Comment: @JBL I am not able to understand them.

Comment: `it->first` is not an iterator, nor a pointer.

Comment: @chotabheem Alright, I had `clang` in mind when I said "self-explanatory" but you may not be using it. In my case, it spits a nice message that says `invalid operands to binary expression (const std::__1::pair<int, int> and int)` which explains nicely why it's not working :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you iterate over your `map`, you can get the following items

```
std::pair<int, int> key = it->first;
int value = it->second;
```

Therefore the `first` and `second` value of the `key` would be

```
it->first.first;
it->first.second;
```

Comment: We don't use  it->first->first here because (it-first)is not a pointer and We don't have to dereference it.Thats why we used simple '.' operator.Am I right ?